# How do I replace random letter from one div with other letter in second div?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have two elements `<input type = text>` and `<div>`. I need help creating the event handler for the input so that anything typed, will be written to the div but will have all occurrences of a particular letter replaced.  For example, if `gjdafrffakja` was typed and I'm replacing "a" with "A", the div would contain `gjdAfrffAkjA.`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
function changeText(obj){
  var res = obj.innerHTML.replace(/a/gi, "A");
  obj.innerHTML=res;
    
  div2.innerHTML=res;
}
```

```html
<div  style="width:100%; height:50px; background-color:pink;"
      contenteditable="true" onkeyup="changeText(this)"></div>
<br><br>
<div id="div2" style="width:100%;height:50px;background-color:yellow;"></div>
```

Comment: This does what I think the OP is trying to accomplish.  It also has the unfortunate side effect of moving carat back to the beginning of the div after each key press.